# Stocktwits api oauth: How to get parameter from request python redirect [ACCESS TOKEN]

Tags: python, oauth

```
import request

url ="https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/oauth/authorize?client_id=[CLIENT_ID]&response_type=token&redirect_uri=http://[YOUR TEST DOMAIN]&scope=read,watch_lists,publish_messages,publish_watch_lists,follow_users,follow_stocks";

print(url);
res = requests.get(url);
print(res)
```

How to access the access_token?

returned URL has the token when run in the browser.

```
http://[YOUR TEST URI]/#access_token=[ACCESS TOKEN]
```

Or is there another way to authenticate?

https://api.stocktwits.com/developers/docs/authentication

Comment: You will find it in the response headers. In some cases you will have to check `response.history`.

Comment: res.history produces [<Response [302]>] @KlausD.i don't see the param in the header either. I do see the param in the web broswer response